# Need help using objects and functions -- new to programming

Tags: c++, function, object

I'm in beginning computer science class and we're currently learning about functions, however I thought that I would take it one step further and start teaching myself about objects early on. I tried to make this Average game score calculator, however upon entering the values 10, 20, 30 and 40 then entering the loop sentinel value of -999. Where I should get an average of 25, as its 100/4, I get 80. I've played around with it quite a bit but just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong exactly -- I try not to ask for help anymore unless I really can't figure something out after a few hours of reading through google and my books. So any help would be much appreciated :)

EDIT: My question is: Why when I enter all these values do they not go through the proper route and get a correct average? (This is my first time ever even attempting to use objects and don't know very much about how to use them, but I figured trial and error would help me learn.)

Thank you in advanced!

P.S I'm new here, but I hope that I formatted this question correctly as to not get anyone mad at me again. Oh and I know I haven't used the iomanip or string libraries yet, however I plan to in the future so I just left them in there.

```
//COMSCI 110
//HUNTER DURNFORD
//INPUT

//SPECIAL COMPILER FUNCTIONS
//NONE

//PROCESSING
//

//DATA
//

//LIBRARIES
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//PROGRAMMER DEFINED FUNCTIONS
//introduction
//

//Object Classes
//AvgScoreCalculator

//Object class
class AvgScoreCalculator
{
private:
//double total_Scores = game_Scores;// The total scores
//double score_Average = total_Scores / score_Count; // the average                 equation
public:
    double total_Scores; // the total that gets input into the average function
    double score_Average; // the average of all the games
    double score_Count; // the counter for each individual game entry
    double game_Scores; // the scores for the individual games
    //char exit_Value;
};//end class

//introduction function
void introduction()
{
    cout << "Enter any amount of characters and this program will encrypt them." << endl;
    cout << "By Hunter Durnford." << endl;
    cout << "Editor(s) used: XCODE TEXT EDITOR and JNotePad 2\n";
    cout << "Compiler(s) used: XCODE\n";
    cout << "File: " << __FILE__ << endl;
    cout << "Complied: " << __DATE__ << " at " << __TIME__ << endl << endl;
}//introduction

//function to get scores from user
double getScoreFunction()
{
    double score_Count = 0.0;
    double gameScores = 0.0;
    double total_Scores = 0.0;

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "What score would you like to input? Or type -999 to exit. ";
        cin >> gameScores;

        if(gameScores == -999)
        {
            break;
        }

        score_Count = score_Count + 1;

        gameScores = gameScores + gameScores;

        total_Scores = gameScores;
    }
    return total_Scores;
}//end score function


//Average of all the scores function
double getAverageFunction(double total_Scores, double score_Count)
{
    double average_Score;
    average_Score = total_Scores / score_Count;

    return average_Score;
}


//main program
int main()
{
    introduction();

    AvgScoreCalculator average_Score; //Declaring the object under the class

    //set the integers for the average_score object
    average_Score.score_Count = 0.0;
    average_Score.game_Scores = 0.0;
    average_Score.score_Average = 0.0;
    average_Score.total_Scores = 0.0;

    average_Score.game_Scores = getScoreFunction();

    average_Score.score_Average = getAverageFunction(average_Score.total_Scores, average_Score.score_Count);

    cout << "The average of all the game scores is: " << average_Score.game_Scores << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: You shouldn't compare `double` values like this: `if(gameScores == -999)`

Comment: should i change that loop to while(gameScores != -999)? the professor told us to have -999 be the sentinel value or else i probably would have used something else.

Comment: In order to find what's wrong, reduce your program. In this case, the question is for example whether input is faulty or the calculation. Check the input independently. If it works, replace it with hard-coded values to test the calculation. Doing that, you should be able to provide a really minimal but still complete example. Chances are that you will find the error yourself on the way.

Comment: @HunterDurnford The problem is the `double` representation of values isn't exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(leaving apart problems with the precision of doubles that has been pointed out in the comments)

Problem here:

```
    score_Count = score_Count + 1;

    gameScores = gameScores + gameScores;

    total_Scores = gameScores;
```

play it in your head:

- gameScores=0.0
- total_Scores=0.0
- ... now you read 10
- gameScores=10.0
- gameScore=gameScore + gameScore -> 10.0 + 10.0 = 20.0
- total_Scores = gameScore = 20.0
- ... next loop just overwrites.

should be:

```
    score_Count = score_Count + 1;

    total_Scores += gameScores;
```

in addition, score_Count is a local variable of `getScoreFunction()`... so its changes do not affect the `average_Score.score_Count` used for the average calculation.

Comment: okay so i ended up moving the total_Scores += gameScores; out of the while loop. Then actually in the output I was using some wrong things also. the only problem now is that score_Count returns nothing to main, so i need to somehow figure out how to get that to return but I'm not sure how to return two integers from the same function

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help thus far though -- this is my first time trying to use objects and it can be a tad daunting.

Comment: @HunterDurnford, main point of an object is that you should be able to do things with it (meaning methods!)... consider turning some of your functions to be methods under AvgScoreCalculator class, they will have access to the class attributes. You can also split the `getScoreFunction()` into the part that reads from the `std::cin` (which might remain a function) and the part that accumulates and count (that can be a method operating on the class attributes).

Comment: I'm going to look into that now, thanks so much for your help. I'm gonna get this down if it kills me haha